# Substract/Compare two table rows in a SQL database

Tags: sql, database

Here is my problem : 
I have a "Machines" table with a column's row looking like this, but longer :

> Microsoft Application Error Reporting
> Microsoft Application
>   Error Reporting
> Microsoft Office Professional Plus
>   2010
> Microsoft Office OneNote MUI (English) 2010
> Microsoft Office InfoPath MUI (English) 2010
> Microsoft
>   Office Access MUI (English) 2010
> Microsoft Office Shared
>   Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2010
> Microsoft Office Excel MUI
>   (English) 2010
> Microsoft Office Shared 64-bit Setup Metadata
>   MUI (English) 2010

And I have a "Exceptions" table, with a column's row like it :

> Microsoft Office OneNote MUI (English) 2010
> Microsoft Office
>   InfoPath MUI (English) 2010

What I'd like to do is taking only the text present in the first table ( and NOT in the second ) and putting it into a third table.

Sorry if I'm not clear, I did my best with my english.. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Here is how my row looks. [Click](http://www.noelshack.com/2012-23-1338902815-osef.png)

Comment: Do you have one large text field or are these stored as separate lines on different rows?

Comment: I've got a large text field (_varchar(MAX)_), all my softwares are in one row.

Comment: Are the exceptions in one row?  Or are they on separate lines?

Comment: In one row too, I did the same way for both of my tables.

Comment: You have a bad database design.  You need two additional tables, MachineSoftware and ExceptionSoftware.  Each of these would have one line per software.

Comment: Ouch... I wished I didn't need to do it. Thanks, I'll look for an easy solution. :)

Comment: With your current db structure not much you can do in SQL alone. Use a scripting language such as Perl to work out the differences between the rows.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I didn't know about Perl. Do you think I could do something similar in C# ?

Comment: Pierre, I would say pretty much your only hope of doing it in SQL is to do a cross join and write a user defined function to do the matchines.  Exporting the data and re-importing it into multiple rows seems like a simpler solution overall.

Comment: If you can re-run your c# program then I would rewrite it to insert the machine software into a seperate table as suggested by others.

Comment: GordonLinoff : Thanks, I think I'll do it so. :)

Bruce : It would be a very long work, my program is composed by big C# dialog box ( I'm not sure about the term ) and a website in ASP.NET & C# ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the rows that are in Machines (without the ones that are in Exceptions), you can select them like this:

```
select *
from Machines
where columnName not in (select columnName from Exceptions)
```

You can then insert them using insert into like this (assuming Machines and the newTable with the same columns):

```
insert into newTableName
select *
from Machines
where columnName not in (select columnName from Exceptions)
```

If they have different columns, you can select them..

---

Since they are in all in the same column and row, you'll need to use `like` to check if they are present and `replace` to delete the needed part if so.

Comment: The problem is that all my softwares are in only one row, like in the link I provided in my first post' edit. Will it work anyway ? :/

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza it won't work. But why do you've all in one row?

Comment: This is because I made a c# program, getting informations about different remote computers ( OS, CPU, Blah blah, installed softwares ) and putting everything in a table, so the OS is in a column, the CPU in another, and the installed softwares are all in the same column too :/

Comment: Why don't you make another columns specifying the type (OS, CPU, etc.), that's the correct way to do it ;)

Comment: Sorry this is what I did but my english is bad so I don't know how to explain it properly :S


For example, I have this for a computer :
Column OS : Windows 7 professionnal |


Column CPU : 2.66GHz |


Column Softwares : Microsoft Office blah, Microsoft blah, Blah blah

Comment: the software should be in different rows. It can be on that table or, possibly, another one.

Comment: Yeh.. I'll see if I can find a way without creating different rows, otherwise I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: It's possible but it'll be hard. You'll need to use `like` to check if it's present and if it is, remove it with `replace`.

Comment: I'll see on the net how to use "like" and "replace", thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
select m.line
from (select distinct line
      from Machines m
     ) left outer join
     Exceptions e
     on m.line = e.line
where e.line is NULL
```

I interpreted your question as Machines has many rows with a line of text in them.  You want the distinct lines in Machines that are not in Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I know my question is old but since I've redone my entire program, I found another answer, so if it can help someone :

```
for (i = 0; i < SplitMachine.Length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < SplitExceptions.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(SplitMachine[i],SplitExceptions[j]) == 0)
                    {
                        ListMachines.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
```

SplitMachine is a string array with my softwares, StringExceptions is a string array with the softwares I don't want to display, so if a string in my SplitMachine matches with a string in SplitExceptions, I remove the concerned string in SplitMachine.

I hope it was clear and can help someone.